# Debugging externally compiled Typescript in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

I was trying to debug typescript with IntelliJ but I cannot get it working. I use webpack to build the typescript files and maps and only the compiled js is used in the page. I also use an external webserver, so I cannot use the build in IDEA webserver.

My structure looks as follows:

```
root
  |-- compiled
    |-- compiled.js
    |-- compiled.js.map  
  |-- src
    |-- file1.ts
    |-- some_subfolder
      |-- file2.ts
    |-- ....
```

I setup a debug configuration for Javascript, installed the Chrome extension and did the path mappings. If I put a breakpoint into `compiled.js`, the breakpoint gets hit and I can debug. Breakpoints in my ts files are ignored though. I did mark the `compiled` folder as excluded as per documentation (it says the IDE will then autoload map files from these folders). As far as I can see there is no option to manually set a map file for the script file in the debug configuration.

Any ideas what I might be missing?